# Symmetric 2-Designs

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-designs

We just proved that for any symmetric 2-design (or Symmetric BIBDs as most literature puts it) with parameters $(v,k,\lambda)$, any two blocks intersects at exactly $\lambda$ points. Our lecturer noted in passing that the converse holds true, but I can't seem to prove it. Wiki says "a theorem of Ryser provides the converse".

Would someone be so kind to provide (or give reference) a proof of this? And note that I'm only doing a first course on algebraic combinatorics so if this converse turns out to be some theorem way harder just let me know as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can show this by considering the dual structure, that is, the structure obtained by reversing the role of "points" and "blocks".  If the original design $\mathcal{D}$ has the property that any two blocks share precisely $\lambda$ points, then the dual structure $\mathcal{D}^{T}$ satisfies the requirements to be a design.  The fact that $\mathcal{D}$ is symmetric then follows from the fact that a design has at least as many blocks as points (applied to both $\mathcal{D}$ and $\mathcal{D}^{T}$). This last result is a generalization of Fisher's inequality.